# Writing and reading to SDcard

Tags: android

I want to make an application that will do something daily. I've managed to get the day saved and, in the next days,and I want it compared to the current day.

Ex:
day=5;
aux=5;

Tomorrow:

day=6;
aux=5;

If(day!=aux) do something
else don't do something

I wanted to save the aux's state on a file on the Sdcard, but it is so hard to find a working code. I hope that someone will take a look and answer it, I would need it for tomorrow.

```
public class Castle extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.castle);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();      
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    int aux=Reading();

    if(day==aux)
    { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Castle.this, Hug.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Castle.this, Hug_Accepted.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (root.canWrite()){
            File file = new File(root, "Tedehlia/state.txt");
            file.mkdir();
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
            out.write(day);
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }}




}
public int Reading()
{int aux = 0;
    try{


       File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/state.txt");

       FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);

       BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));

       String readString = new String();

       if((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){

          aux=Integer.parseInt(readString.toString());


       }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e){

       e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return aux;
}
```

}

Comment: But what's the issue? Do you get an Exception? (in your catch clauses print the exception to LogCat)

Comment: I will test it right now. I'm 100% sure it will not work. I'm not even sure if the file will be created.

Comment: I would also want just one value to be saved on the file. I think that I might need to delete the file after I get the value from it, can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Btw are you using the SD Card for a specific reason? For storing/retrieving a simple int you can use SharedPreferences: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Can you show me how to use this SharedPreferences? I don't really understand your documentation.

Comment: There is an example at that link. Take a look. Try it. PS. it's not "my documentation" (it's Google's ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to read the file before the app has a chance to create it. I would strongly suggest that you use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) instead of a file on the SDCard for this.

```
public void onCreate() {
    . . .
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int aux = prefs.getInt("AUX", -1);
    if (day == aux) {
        . . .
    } else {
        aux = day;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("AUX", day);
        editor.apply(); // or editor.commit() if API level < 9
    }
    . . .
}
```

Comment: So, this will save my "aux"'s state even if the application closes?

Comment: @AnTz - Absolutely. That's one of the nice things about SharedPreferences. Also, despite their name, they are private to your application.

Comment: @Ted: `editor.putInt(day, "AUX");` - You got the key and value the wrong way around.

Comment: @MisterSquonk - D'oh. Thanks for the catch. Fixed now.